# How to solve Error at lidR::delineate_crowns?

Tags: r, lidr

Processing a script I wrote a couple of month ago with an older version old lidR causes an error with current version.
name of functions changed from `lidR::tree_hulls` to `lidR::delineate_crowns`

It worked with the old version but doesn't with the new version.

**sample data:**
https://github.com/anayana/so_sampla_data/blob/main/so_sample_las.laz
(there might be better ways to share data, tips are welcome)

**sample code:**

```
so_sample_las <- readLAS("so_sample_las.laz")
tree.hulls <- lidR::delineate_crowns(clean_las, type="concave", attribute="treeID")
```

**error message**

```
Error in (function (cond)  : 
                error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'addAttrToGeom': Evaluation error:
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4.
```

**what I tried:**

remove all points that belong to a treeID which is represented by less than 4 entries
create LAS without points of underrepresented treeIDs

```
so_sample_las_dat <- so_sample_las@data
clean_dat <- las.so_sample_las_dat [so_sample_las_dat $treeID %in% names(which(table(so_sample_las_dat $treeID) > 4)), ]

clean_las <- so_sample_las
clean_las@data <- clean_dat
clean_tree.hulls <- lidR::delineate_crowns(clean_las, type="concave", attribute="treeID")
```

**error message**

```
Error in (function (cond)  : 
                error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'addAttrToGeom': Evaluation error:
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found
3 - must be 0 or >= 4.
```

same error message appeared. Maybe I don't understand the error message or did another mistake.
any hint is welcome!

Comment: This look like a bug report

Comment: wrote a bug report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested both with `delineate_crown()` (deprecated) and `crown_metrics()`. Both work. `delineate_crown()` produces warnings but they can be ignored.

```r
library(lidR)
so_sample_las <- readLAS("so_sample_las.laz")
tree.hulls.1 <- delineate_crowns(so_sample_las, type="concave", attribute="treeID") 
tree.hulls.2 <- crown_metrics(so_sample_las,  func = NULL,  geom = "concave", attribute = "treeID")
```

Update your packages and if you still encounter troubles report a bug.

Comment: thx for your answer! However, trying to run delineate_crowns results still in the same error. As it runs on your system but not on mine: What could be the reason? packages are updated. R 4.1.1, lidR 4.0.1, all other packages are also updated.